# Trigger TeamCity build only when detecting changes in .java files on VCS checkout

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Is there a command or parameter in TeamCity wherein it will only trigger the build if there's at least one java file that's committed when doing VCS checkout? I'm using TeamCity 8.1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify [VCS Trigger Rules](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-VCSTriggerRules) and use wild cards to specify java files. Something like

[image]

Comment: +1 for this, but I think check on option 'Trigger a build on each check-in' is not needed as with trigger rules alone build will get triggered?.